# Subscribe to latest n emissions of Observable

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have an Observable that emits Integers:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

which will emit `1,2,3,4`

How can I apply a function that operates over the last `n` emissions, like (pseudo code)

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4).doWithLatest(2, { i1, i2 -> i1 + i2 })
```

(2 being the number of emissions the function should be applied to)

that would emit `3,5,7` (the sum of the last two emissions, as supplied as a function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a sliding buffer:

```
Observable.range(1, 4)
.buffer(2, 1)
.filter(list -> list.size() == 2)
.map(list -> list.get(0) + list.get(1))
.test()
.assertResult(3, 5, 7);
```